# Is it possible for custom sorting in ExtJS 3.2 for date

Tags: java, extjs, extjs3

I have one `store` which is getting date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. I want to sort this date in my `ExtJS grid`  in such way that all the date of same month should display one after the other and next other month date should be displayed. But what is happening is that in `ExtJS` all the dates are treated as string, so I am getting output as `01-01-2015` next date is `01-02-2015` which I don't want. So is it possible for custom sorting in ExtJS 3.2`?

**Code snippet:**

```
var memebersListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    name: 'approverlist',
    autoLoad: true,
    url: 'json/loginLogout.do?Uid=' + userLdapId + '&startDate=' + selectedStartDate + '&endDate=' + selectedEndDate,
    fields: ['weekDate'],
    sortInfo: {
        field: 'weekDate',
        direction: 'ASC'
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function (store, records, options) {
            if (store.getTotalCount() === 0) {
                memebersListStoreGrid.reconfigure(store, columnsTwo);
            } else {
                memebersListStoreGrid.reconfigure(store, columnsOne);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

in fields you have to define type. like this

```
 fields: [{name: 'weekDate', type: 'DATE'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for response .This way it is converting in IST pattern.So Now I changed into YYY-mm-dd format so this way it takes all the month date in sequnce..

Comment: you can also use extjs converter for that